# Google Calendar API InvalidArgumentException : "Invalid Code"

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Okay so far I've been following the listed [php tutorial](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) that Google has provided, I have gathered my client secret, I have set my Redirect URI to port localhost:8000 and have listed the directory for my credentials/client_secret accordingly. I'm now in the final step which is authorizing my application in order for me to be a productive spawn of society and use this fantastic calendar library.

I'm getting this error once in the stage of authorizing my account, (which is strange because I'm able to get the correct URL to authorize my application (*the URL works and redirects to the correct URI*) and get the code needed but I'm not able to input it in because it seems as if it takes in nothing willingly without waiting for me to put the code in):

```
C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's>php quickstart.php
<Open the following link in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=316595803597-m0irohklrarshii5lj7mugkghi48v84v.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&prompt=select_account%20consent
Enter verification code: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid code in C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php:176
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\quickstart.php(44): Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('')
#1 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\quickstart.php(63): getClient()
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on line 176

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid code in C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php:176
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\quickstart.php(44): Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('')
#1 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\quickstart.php(63): getClient()
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on line 176
```

bloody well right

here's where it's throwing the exception (*API's\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on line 176*):

```
public function fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code)
  {
    if (strlen($code) == 0) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid code");  //exception thrown here
    }

    $auth = $this->getOAuth2Service();
    $auth->setCode($code);
    $auth->setRedirectUri($this->getRedirectUri());

    $httpHandler = HttpHandlerFactory::build($this->getHttpClient());
    $creds = $auth->fetchAuthToken($httpHandler);
    if ($creds && isset($creds['access_token'])) {
      $creds['created'] = time();
      $this->setAccessToken($creds);
    }

    return $creds;
  }
```

is there something wrong with my credentials? I have but a clue what may be going on because I've tried in the past and have never experienced this error, I usually get something along the lines of the redirect URI not being correct. Any and all help is welcome. **TYIA**.

EDIT (read comment) :

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#2 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandl in C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#2 C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandl in C:\wamp64\www\Main\Career\EricksFuckingWebsite\API's\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187
```

Comment: Why are you setting code and what are you setting as code?

Comment: there needs to be an authentication code in order for my app to be verified for the google api, the code is supposed to be given once I authorize my application with my gmail respectively.

Comment: I've done some digging, it appears that there is a problem with STDIN, and the way in which it is supposed to wait for input. I have no idea as to why it's not doing it's job, I tried replacing with readline but it then gives me an error stating that fgets expects a resource which I know now is a give and the way the code is structured it's supposed to work, if anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it as i've been stuck for way too long with this. TYIA

Comment: I've seen a post that replaced STDIN with the code that they got (*I did the same and I get the same error*)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about it the wrong way remember code is only used once its is an authorization code after that you will need to either store the refresh token or require that the user login again once it has expired.

## oauth2callback.php

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secrets.json you downloaded from the Developers Console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

## index.php

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);


// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $service= new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

  // Call The method which will call the Api
  $response = getCalendar($service);

  // Print the response.
  printResults($response);

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I have another example where which shows how to store the refresh token. [Calendar api sample](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3)